# How do I get a redirect url for my expo mobile app to authenticate with the ecobee api OAuth?

Tags: react-native, oauth-2.0, expo, ecobee-api

I am working on integrating thermostat APIs into my mobile app. Nest and Honeywell both accept our redirect URL fine for the OAuth flow using an authorization code but ecobee's developer portal says the URL is not valid. The app is written in React Native using Expo.

Currently, I am using `WebBrowser.openAuthSessionAsync` to open the webview and login to authenticate and it will receive the redirect containing the auth code. Ecobee will not accept the `Constants.linkingUri` as a valid URL. I found the `AuthSession` package for Expo that solves this problem for the facebook API but ecobee still does not accept https://auth.expo.io/@your-username/your-app-slug as a valid redirect URL.

I know that this is possible for mobile apps to authenticate with ecobee using the OAuth authorization code method because IFTT does it.